# citations shown as zeros

Tags: bibtex, lyx

In LyX, I added a BibTeX biography to the end of the document, and several citations in the document body. In the PDF, I can see the correct references at the end, but in the document body, the references appear as zeros: "(0)".

Interestingly, inside LyX the citations are shown just fine, for example:

> ... Such methods were used in the first documented dialog systems Weizenbaum (1966) ...

In the PDF, instead of "Weizenbaum (1966)", I see "(0)".

I am new to LaTeX and LyX, so I have no idea how to debug this...